# HTML5 Download issue with Firefox Only When data is from Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, download

I want to download a **JSON** file from a server, In google Chrome it is Working fine, But in Firefox its not getting downloaded but opening in a new page.

**NB : Firefox download is working fine with Local files**

How to Solve this issue

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/dineshkanivu/24tq2da5/1/

**Here is My Code**

```
<a href="http://christtravels.com/js/dk.json" download="some.json">
  Clicked
</a>
```

Comment: Maybe it does not work in your sample because it is not of the same origin? See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Comment: Actually, Firefox now only supports same-origin download links

Comment: @adeneo I am Using Firefox 44. Firefox is Downloading file from Local, But From Server its not

Comment: Probably because it's cross-origin

Comment: @Mr. Alien Can you der To Help Me

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you:

HTML:

```
<a href="test.php">Clicked</a>
```

in test.php:

```
$download_name = 'http://christtravels.com/js/dk.json';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename = ' . $download_name);
ob_clean();
flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `download` attribute should contain the downloaded file name or just be empty so try `download="some.json"` and see if that works

Comment: Isn't `download` a valid filename, too?

Comment: depends on what classes as a filename in the browser, I would assume a filename would have an extension. However I have not looked into the specifics of it, you could optionally just remove the filename and put in `download` without any values. However like most other people say this is probably more likely a CORS issue.